# State is not updating in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui-react

I met a problem when I use *semantic-ui-react(version: 0.78.3)*. I was trying to use `onSearchChange` function in Dropdown. I changed states with `this.setState` in `onSearchChange` function.

But when I input the first alphabet, the query state doesn't change at all(still empty). When I input the second alphabet, the query state will change into the first alphabet.

Here is the code:

```js
class SearchBookForm extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    loading: false,
    options: [{
      key: 1,
      value: 1,
      text: 'first book'
    }]
  }

  onSearchChange = (e, data) => {
    
    // log four different variables before this.setState
    console.log(data.searchQuery)
    console.log(this)
    console.log(this.state.query)
    console.log(this.state.loading);
    
    this.setState({ query: data.searchQuery, loading: !this.state.loading });

    // log one variable after this.setState
    console.log(this.state.query)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Form>
        <Dropdown
          search
          fluid
          placeholder="Search for a book by title"
          onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}
          options={this.state.options}
          loading={this.state.loading}
        />
      </Form>
    )
  }
};
```

To make it more clear, I log four variables in onSearchChange function, when I type "p" in the form, the log result is as follows: [Log result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4uWZ.png)

`data.searchQuery` changes into p. In `this`, its state(query and loading) has been changed, although `this.setState` is at the end of the function. But the third and fifth variables `this.state.query` are nothing and the fourth variable `this.state.loading` doesn't change as well.

When I type the second alphabet "l", `this.state.query` changes into "p", and `this.state.loading` changes as well. It seems setState works, but always falls behind. The result pic is here: [Log result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKxkf.png)

I hope my explanation makes sense. I am so confused. Is it a bug in semantic-ui-react? What is the logic in onSearchChange function?

Comment: let me know if you have any doubt?

Comment: Before setState, why the state changes when log "this", but not "this.state.query"?

Comment: when you are printing the this, there will be any `i` icon near to object, hover over that icon and see what it prints. value of array/object will be evaluated when you expand the object/array in console so it will always print the updated/latest value but when you print any value it will print the value at that moment not the updated one, hope you will get the idea :)